# Pass data from android phone(WiFi) to PC(LAN)

Tags: android, networking, udp, android-wifi, lan

I need pass data(string) from my mobile that connected using WiFi to my computer that connected using LAN. **How can I do it in Android ?** WiFi and LAN are in same network.

Thanks

**Edit**
I have to use UDP. Stream video using UDP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Establish a socket connection between the two devices and then use that connection to send data. One device should work as a server and the other as a client. Don't forget to add the right permission to the Android manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Read about a socket connection here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/

Comment: Thanks for your quick replay but I want to use streaming over **UDP**. Can you suggest any working example...